# React/Redux - Making separate fetch call on individual routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I have a redux store which I want to connect to my App, but I also want to only fetch data relevant to the specific component that is being rendering by react-router.

At the moment it is connected to a container element (`App.js`) which then feeds all props to the router's children. This feels a bit clumsy though.

Here is what I have:

### App.js

```
class App extends Component { 
    render() { 

       return ( 
          <div> 
             {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
          </div> 
       ) 
    } 
 } 

 const mapStateToProps = (state, { params }) => { 
    {/*all props here*/}
    } 
 } 

 // connect App component to redux store
 App = withRouter(connect( 
    mapStateToProps, 
    actions 
)(App)); 

export default App;
```

### Root.js

```
const Root = ({ store }) => ( 
    <Provider store={store}> 
       <Router history={browserHistory}> 
          <Route path='/' component={App}>
             <Route path='/users' component={Users} />
             <Route path='/posts' component={Posts} />
          </Route> 
       </Router> 
    </Provider> 
 ) 

 export default Root;
```

So as you can see react router takes care of which component is being rendered. I want to render the component based on the active route according to react router, **and on `componentDidMount`, make the relevant data fetch**.

### Users.js

```
class Users extends Component {
   render() {
       componentDidMount() {
          fetchData(users) 
       }
       return (
          <div>Users content here...</div>
       )
   }
}
```

### Posts.js

```
class Posts extends Component {
   render() {
       componentDidMount() {
          fetchData(posts) 
       }
       return (
          <div>Posts content here...</div>
       )
   }
}
```

As you can see I would be making a separate call to the API based on the mounted component to determine which endpoint to call.

However this seems repetitious and I imagine it's bad practice. Is there a more concise/elegant way to achieve what I am going for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `@Decorator` such as this one:

This way, you can maintain all of the data fetching code in one place, and only pass the route for the data you need.

If you're unfamiliar with how these work, [here's](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.hvyvkkm6g) some reading material

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import URL from 'API'
import axios from 'axios';

const decorator = ComposedComponent => {
  const component = class extends Component {
    get = (path, params) => {
      return fetch(`${URL}/${path}`, { params }).then(res => res.json());
    };

    post = (url, params) => {
      return axios.post(url, params);
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          {...this.props}
          get={::this.get}
          post={::this.post}
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return component;
};

export default decorator;
module.exports = decorator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `fetch` all you want on `onEnter` hook from `react-router`. From [**`spec`**](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/Glossary.md#enterhook)

> An *enter* hook is a user-defined function that is called when a route
>   is about to be rendered
>
> If an enter hook needs to execute asynchronously, it may list a 3rd
>   callback argument that it must call in order to cause the transition
>   to proceed.

```
<Route path="/users" component={User} onEnter={fetchUsers}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: That's worth a try, thanks. But is there not an easier way using react-router-redux?

Comment: @Paulos3000 you can have a look at [this link](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router/issues/66) and follow the similar idea